# Why does sqlQuery from SAP HANA using RODBC return no data if request 18 or more rows

Tags: r, hana, rodbc

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with HANA Client installed and an ODBC connection to an SAP HANA database. In the ODBC Data Source administrator, I have added a connection to the required database and can successfully connect.

I am trying to use RStudio to retrieve data for analysis using R. I am finding that queries that return a handful of rows ("TOP 1" to "TOP 17") successfully return all 71 columns of data for the requested number of rows, but when I query with "TOP 18" or higher number of rows, I get all column titles, but 0 rows returned.

So the query:

```
res<-sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT TOP 17 * FROM "SAPL2P"."/BIC/PZRPA_CNO" WHERE "/BIC/ZRPA_DCD"=\'CONFIRMED\'')
```

results in 17 rows of data, but

```
res2<-sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT TOP 18 * FROM "SAPL2P"."/BIC/PZRPA_CNO" WHERE "/BIC/ZRPA_DCD"=\'CONFIRMED\'')
```

has 0 rows of data.

Any ideas what could be causing data not to be returned for more than 17 rows?

Comment: When running the queries in SAP HANA Studio, are all records returned?

Comment: I don't have HANA Studio installed. I might see if I can get it installed, but it should not be necessary. In the meantime, I'll ask a colleague to check if they get results back in HANA STUDIO.

Comment: From HANA STUDIO, the query does return the expected 18 records when run with TOP 18. TOP 200 also returned the top 200 records.

Comment: From the data extracted via HANA STUDIO, I do notice that in the 18th record, there is a character field that contains a Lithuanian character (an "E" with a dot above it). The first 17 rows do not have any such characters. Could this be a cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem here really is how R on Windows handles UTF data from ODBC (as already has been described).
A quick search around SO shows that this problem is pretty common for R on Windows with a lot of different DBMS.

For SAP HANA what worked for me was to add the following parameter to the ODBC DSN (in the ODBC driver settings -> Settings... -> Special property settings):

CHAR_AS_UTF8 | TRUE

This makes SAP HANA ODBC to handle SQL_C_CHAR as UTF8.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. This change does enable the rows with accented characters to be returned, but the characters are converted incorrectly. Looks like there might be a further issue with codepages. Can this also be configured via the ODBC property settings, to use cp1257, for example?

Comment: OK, I found it! In addition to the above solution, I needed to indicate UTF-8 as the DBMS encoding when I opened the channel in RStudio: 'ch<-odbcConnect("HANA_QA_DS",uid="aaaaaaaa",pwd="bbbbbbbb", DBMSencoding="UTF-8")'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. At first, I had no rows returns at all. Adding believeNRows=FALSE and rows_at_time=1 to the initial connection helped in at least bringing back some data (until a failure occurred). In my case, I could only retrieve 5 rows with the 6th one failing which helped me to identify the problem row in the database.

In the end, I believe it has to do with encoding as per your suggestion above. I found that my issue was with the inverted single quote character.

I found the following information on the RODBC cran site:

> The other
> internationalization issue is the character encoding used. When R and
> the DBMS are running on the same machine this is unlikely to be an
> issue, and in many cases the ODBC driver has some options to translate
> character sets. SQL is an ANSI (US) standard, and DBMSs tended to
> assume that character data was ASCII or perhaps currently this is
> stymied by bugs in the ODBC driver, so SQLColumns is unable to report
> on tables in specified databases. More recently DBMSs have started to
> (optionally or by default) to store data in Unicode, which
> unfortunately means UCS-2 on Windows and UTF-8 elsewhere. So cross OS
> solutions are not guaranteed to work, but most do.

SAP HANA is a database that store data in Unicode.

I tried various options to set the encoding:

1. setting the DBMSencoding property in the RODBS.odbcConnect proc to UTF-8, latin1, ISO8859-1 and UCS-2 without any luck
2. I also tried setting the encoding in RStudio itself without luck

In the end, I settled on creating a view in SAP HANA to replace the problem character in SQL.
`replace(content,x,y) as content` where x was the problem character and y the replacement.

From that point on RODBC could retrieve the data without problem.

Comment: Looks like you had the 2nd half of the solution - adding the DBMSencoding property. :)

Comment: Glad it helped @db533. Unfortunately I still cannot get it to work on my side even after adding the CHAR_AS_UTF8 in my ODBC DSN. Could you perhaps tell me if you used TRUE or 1 as the value for the variable. In addition are you using the HDBODBC driver and which version? Thanks, Estee

Comment: I used TRUE as the value for the variable. Yes, I am using the HDBODBC driver. Version is 1.00.112.04. Filename is LIBODBCHDB.DLL

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to require 2 parts as the issue arose due to Baltic characters within the SAP data. The 2 steps were:

- Adding the property 'CHAR_AS_UTF8' with a value of 'TRUE' in the ODBC DSN settings as Lars suggested above.
- Opening the channel in RStudio with an extra parameter 'DBMSencoding="UTF-8"‌'​

So the RStudio command to open the channel to the HANA data is now:
ch<-odbcConnect("HA‌​NA_QA_DS",uid="aaaaaa‌​aa",pwd="bbbbbbbb", DBMSencoding="UTF-8"‌​)

Thanks, Lars. Your input was instrumental to solving this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
Adding the property 'CHAR_AS_UTF8' = 1 was not an option for me, since it has to be defined on the system of every new user using the code.

In my solution I cast the column to NCLOB.

```
res<-sqlQuery(ch, 'SELECT TO_NCLOB("COLUMNNAME") as "COLUMNNAME" FROM "SAPL2P"."MYSCHEMA"')
```

This might be complicated on the selection of *. However, mostly only certain known columns are affected by undesired characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$host;Database=$db_name;CHAR_AS_UTF8=TRUE;", $username, $password,SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER);
```

this is the sample connection how to give CHAR_AS_UTF8=TRUE in ODBC.