# PHP ODBC Query only return 4 rows

Tags: php, sql, odbc, hana

I try to execute a stored procedure in a hana database using php, using this code

```
$sql="call sp_stockdisponible";
                            
$cursor+=$limite;
$query=$this->conexion($sql);

while($dataProducto=odbc_fetch_array($query))
{
   $sabanaProductosStock[]=$dataProducto;
}
```

But, only returns 4 records, when should return more than 8.000.

¿What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

What have I tried

- Modify php.ini to work with ODBC
- Put the SQL code in a PHP script and inside HANA DB
- using LIMIT and OFFSET

What am I expect to happen? I need to return the 8.000 records.

Actually, just return 4.

Comment: Does the stored procedure have multiple `SELECT` queries? This will only loop over the results of the first query.

Comment: It would be difficult to answer without knowing what the procedure `sp_stockdisponible` is actually doing.

Comment: PHP uses ODBC to access HANA databases, so this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38987648/4191767 might be the solution to the problem described.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank everybody who takes a little time to answer this. 

After a while, I found that some tables that I was querying has spaces and special characters in its name, i.e. 'año registro'. I try to make the same consult with another table without these, and it worked. 

Maybe this could help to someone.